# Can't access the image under drawable folder in AS

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources

I can't access the image under drawable folder even though I have cleaned and rebuilt the project.

[image]

Comment: share your districts class , anyway you should always capitalize your class name .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reimport your images into drawable folder and this time select main drawable folder, in directory selection prompt, see the image below, select highlighted one while importing images.[image: Select res\drawable folder while importing images]

Comment: can you provide stack strace from AS? and don not import images into Drawable v27 Directory.

Comment: some plugins were disabled, a balloon pops up the problem when I enabled it works fine anyway thanks for u r help